# grabbing all of one value type from a collection

Tags: javascript, arrays, collections

I'm working on a Discord.js bot trying to add roles to mentioned users in a command.  it stores all of the mention data for the message in a collection msg.mentions.users and looks something like this.

```
  '189920214777856000' => User {
 id: '189920214777856000',
 username: 'Warburp',
 discriminator: '2542',
 avatar: 'e83b4777a8abfd7f4cfc0f04761520b4',
 bot: false,
 status: 'online',
 game: null } }
```

What Id would like to do is collect all of the id's that were mentioned into an array so I can use a for loop too add them all to a role.  Distinct is not recognized when I try to use it and find required I add a value and only finds exactly what I specify.

Comment: Place the users into an array, Loop through them with ``array[index].id``, right?

Comment: That would be to goal the issue I'm running into I should've mentioned this adding .id returns undefined.

Comment: Backtrack until you find that the ID isn't being passed at some point. I would suggest checking if it was nullified anywhere but it's not even ``null``.

Comment: Idk where to backtrack too because I'm not creating it. the collection is part of the API I'm just trying to put it into an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Collection.keyArray()](https://discord.js.org/#!/docs/tag/master/class/Collection?scrollto=keyArray) is possibly what you're looking for. From what I understand msg.mentions.users is a Collection object mapping IDs to User objects. So something like this will give you an array of the user IDs:

```
msg.mentions.users.keyArray()
```

Comment: Perfect! that's exactly what I was looking for.  I saw that in the docs but guess I just didn't understand what it did.